# Is emulator supoort is available for Alexa Auto sdk

Tags: android, linux, sdk, android-emulator, android-automotive

If I was able to build Alexa auto sdk successfully without any error then the result of this will be an apk .So is it possible to lunch the apk on android emulator.

Answer (score 0):

It should be. Here's the codelab for spinning up the emulator for Android Automotive: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/automotive-getting-started/index.html?index=..%2F..index#4